# Error inserting Date into SQL Server with Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am modifying a system that was already made, to insert and show columns is being done with a tNGs library, I don't really understand how it works.

The problem is that there is a line of code where a date column is added and inserted

```
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.addColumn "fecha", "DATE_TYPE", "POST", "fecha", ""
```

when inserting this, the error is for the date, example:

I set the date to

```
12/12/2021
```

and when inserting it becomes like this:

```
2021/12/2012
```

If to the code to add the column I leave it like this:

```
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.addColumn "fecha", "STRING_TYPE", "POST", "fecha", ""
```

So the date becomes:

```
2021/12/12
```

But I want:

```
12/12/2021
```

Any thoughts on this?

This is my complete code:

```
 <%
' Make an insert transaction instance 
Dim ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev: Set ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev = new tNG_multipleInsert
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.init MM_oConn_STRING
tNGs.addTransaction ins_sola
' Register triggers
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.registerTrigger Array("STARTER", "Trigger_Default_Starter", 1, "POST", "KT_Insert1")
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.registerTrigger Array("BEFORE", "Trigger_Default_FormValidation", 10, formValidation)
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.registerTrigger Array("END", "Trigger_Default_Redirect", 99, "cerrar.asp")
' Add columns
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.setTable "sola"
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.addColumn "otrocontexto", "STRING_TYPE", "POST", "otrocontexto", ""
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.addColumn "fecha", "STRING_TYPE", "POST", "fecha", ""
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.addColumn "hora", "STRING_TYPE", "POST", "hora", ""
ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.setPrimaryKey "id", "NUMERIC_TYPE", "", ""
%>
```

Comment: Dates have no format, they are a binary representation of the date. The format is only when you display so I suggest you look at formatting options

Comment: Impossible to help you wince we do not know the code of the **tNG_multipleInsert** class, along with its code and the way it handles dates...

Answer (score 1):

> But I want: 12/12/2021
>
> Any thoughts on this?

You're not working directly with ADO, so we have no idea what

`ins_Tis_ServiciosPrev.addColumn "fecha", "DATE_TYPE", "POST", "fecha", ""`

does or why it's not working for you.

But sending the date as a string can be made to work.

When sending a date as a string to SQL Server use the format `YYYYMMDD`, which will be converted correctly in every culture.

If that doesn't work, you may have to find the source code for `tNG_multipleInsert` and post that.